# Transforming columns to row values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Have a table in Google Bigquery like this with 1 id column (customers) and 3 store-name columns:

```
id  |PA|PB|Mall|
----|--|--|----|
3699|1 |1 | 1  |  
1017|  |1 | 1  | 
9991|1 |  |    |
```

My objective is to have the option to select customers (id's)  who visited for example:

- ONLY PA
- PA and PB
- PA and Mall
- PA, PB and Mall

**One alternative** output could be:

```
id  |Store     |
----|--------- |
3699|PA+PB+Mall|
1017|PB+Mall   |
9991|PA        |
```

However this would not give me counts of all stopping by PA regardless of other stores visited. In the example above that count would have been 2 (3699 and 9991).

**A second alternative** output could be:

```
id  |Store|
----|-----|
3699|PA   |
3699|PB   |
3699|Mall |
1017|PB   |
1017|Mall |
9991|PA   |
```

However, this would not allow me (i think) to select/filter those who has visited for example BOTH PA and Mall (only 3699)

**A third alternative** output could be a combo:

```
id  |Store| Multiple store|
----|-----|---------------|
3699|PA   | PA+PB+Mall    |
3699|PB   | PA+PB+Mall    |
3699|Mall | PA+PB+Mall    |
1017|PB   | PB+Mall       |
1017|Mall | PB+Mall       |
9991|PA   |               |
```

What option is the best and is there any other alternatives to achieve my objective? I believe alternative 3 could be best, but not sure how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want.  For instance, the third would simply be:

```
select t.*,
       string_agg(store, '+') over (partition by id)
from t;
```

The second would be:

```
select id, string_agg(store, '+')
from t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

For the third option, you may try unpivoting your current table, then applying `STRING_AGG` to get the computed column containing all stores for each `id`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, CASE WHEN PA = 1 THEN 'PA' END AS Store
    FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, CASE WHEN PB = 1 THEN 'PB' END
    FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, CASE WHEN Mall = 1 THEN 'Mall' END
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, Store,
       STRING_AGG(store, '+') OVER (PARTITION BY id) All_Stores
FROM cte
WHERE Store IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id, Store;
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approaches to all three options

Assuming input data is filled with nulls when it is empty in question's sample

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 3699 id, 1 PA, 1 PB, 1 Mall union all
  select 1017, null, 1, 1 union all
  select 9991, 1, null, null
)
```

Option #1

```
select id, string_agg(key, '+') as Store 
from `project.dataset.table` t,
unnest(split(translate(to_json_string(t), '{}"', ''))) kv,
unnest([struct(split(kv,':')[offset(0)] as key, split(kv,':')[offset(1)] as value)])
where key !='id' 
and value != 'null'
group by id
```

with output

[image]

Option #2

```
select id, key as Store
from `project.dataset.table` t,
unnest(split(translate(to_json_string(t), '{}"', ''))) kv,
unnest([struct(split(kv,':')[offset(0)] as key, split(kv,':')[offset(1)] as value)])
where key !='id' 
and value != 'null'
```

with output

[image]

Option #3

```
select id, key as Store, 
  string_agg(key, '+') over(partition by id) as Multiple_Store 
from `project.dataset.table` t,
unnest(split(translate(to_json_string(t), '{}"', ''))) kv,
unnest([struct(split(kv,':')[offset(0)] as key, split(kv,':')[offset(1)] as value)])
where key !='id' 
and value != 'null'
```

with output

[image]